# Google Translation API v2: Allowing certain HTTP referrers

Tags: http, google-api, google-translate

I am using client-side Google's translation API (v2), which means my API Key would be public visible to everyone. I am calling **/translate** method by AJAX.

Under Google > Credentials > API Key -> Key restrictions -> Application restrictions

I want to allow API being called from only i.e. *www.aliceandbob.com* domain.

After adding this domain under: **HTTP referrers (web sites)**. I am getting 403 forbidden error, but when I set manually http referer header into my http request it passes and API responds me with answer.

```
    function sendPost($data)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
-->       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.aliceanbob.com");
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

And passing data like

$data = array('q' => 'this is world', 'target' => 'de', 'key' => "#my_api_key#");

> Responses OK 200.

But when I remove:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.aliceandbob.com");
```

I got response:

> 403 Forbidden Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.

Any idea how to prevent only one website (domain) can invoke API calls properly, but not letting any other person manually set http referer and act domain (**www.aliceandbob.com**)?

Comment: This looks like php code which would run in a php server so your API key would not be visible to everyone. Am I missing something? Anyway there is a github [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues/483#issuecomment-304689511) where you can see that the referer header is not set by default and you have to pass it. Is there some reason why this would not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In Application restrictions - HTTP referrers (web sites) you must add: `http://www.aliceandbob.com/*` or: `http://*.aliceandbob.com/*`

[image]